# (JavaScript/AJAX) xmlhttp.response pipe updates twice, then stops updating

Tags: javascript, ajax

We use firmware to write to the httpxml.response pipe. Data changes the first (exactly) two writes, and then it doesn't change until the FW is restarted and the web page is reloaded.

I've been through the FW, and there are no state variables that would affect the operation.
Here is the code:
...`

```
function getStatus() {
    var url = './cgi-bin/status';
    var xmlhttp;
    
  if ( workerPaused ) {
    return;
  }
    if ( XMLHttpRequest ) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    
    if ( xmlhttp ) {
        
        if( disconnectCount++ > MAX_DISCONNECT ) {
            disconnectCount = 0;
            if ( typeof(disablePage) == 'function' ) {
                disablePage();
            }
            else {
                postMessage('disablePage');
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.onload = function() {
            if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
                if ( xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {  
                    var status;
                    if ( xmlhttp.response ) {
                        if ( JSON ) {
                            status = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.response);
                        }
                        else {
                            status = eval(xmlhttp.response);
                        }
                        if ( status ) {
                                disconnectCount = 0;
                            if ( typeof(onStatusMessage) == 'function' ) {
                                var msg = {};
                                msg.data = status;
                                onStatusMessage(msg);
                            }
                            else {
                                postMessage(status);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if ( xmlhttp.status == 404 ) {
                    if ( failedRespCounts++ > MAX_FAILED_RESP ) {
                        failedRespCounts = 0;
                        if ( typeof(goToLogin) == 'function' ) {
                            goToLogin();
                        }
                        else {
                            postMessage('goToLogin');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        if (JSON){
            xmlhttp.responseType ='JSON';
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp.responseType ="text";`enter code here`
        }
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

'...

Comment: How many times is `getStatus` called?  The AJAX request will only execute once when `getStatus` is called.

Comment: getStatus is called once a second.

Comment: It looks like a few `console.log` could help you making sure `getStatus` is called and running as expected.